# SQL - Get top 5 values for each group

Tags: sql, sybase

I really would like some help with the following query from SQL Sybase tables.
I would like to see if the top 5 `StressResults` for each `PortfolioID` for any given Date 
There may be duplicate `StressResults` for different `StressTest` for any portfolio.

I would really appreciate any input.

There are four columns `(PortfolioID, Date, StressTest, StressResult)` in table named `StressResultsTable` and two columns `(StressTest, Limits)` in table named `StressScenariosTable`.

Here is my sample query which is the universe.

```
SELECT a.PortfolioID, a.Date, a.StressTest, a.StressResult from StressResultsTable a    join StressScenariosTable b on a.StressTest = b.StressTest
 WHERE a.PortfolioID IN ('Portfolio A', 'Portfolio B') 
   AND a.StressResult <> 0 AND a.Date >= '2013-06-20' and b.Limits = 1
 ORDER BY a.PortfolioID, a.Date, a.StressResult
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below Code :

```html
select a.PortfolioID, a.Date, a.StressTest, a.StressResult from StressResultsTable a 
where
    (
        select count(b.*) from from StressResultsTable b
        WHERE a.PortfolioID=b.PortfolioID
        and a.StressResult=b.StressResult
    ) <= 5
and 
a.PortfolioID IN ('Portfolio A', 'Portfolio B') 
AND a.StressResult <> 0 AND a.Date >= '2013-06-20'
```